# AngularJS Directive Not Evaluating Object Properly

Tags: javascript

I'm using objects improperly somehow. Basically, I want:

```
angular.module('mobileDashboardApp')
    .directive('localForageModel', function ($localForage) {
        return {
            link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {
                scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function () {
                    $localForage.setItem(attrs.localForageModel, scope[attrs.ngModel]);
                    console.log(attrs.ngModel);
                    console.log(scope[attrs.ngModel]);
                    console.log(scope.user.companyId);
                    console.log(scope["user.companyId"]);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

to output

```
user.companyId
dsf
dsf
dsf
```

instead of the current output which is:

```
user.companyId
undefined
dsf
undefined
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or suggest a better title for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have incorrect notation, it must be

```
var props = attrs.ngModel.split(".");
scope[props[0]][props[1]]
```

As dot notations are not valid for dynamic properties, so `object['abc.def']` must be written as `object['abc']['def']`

Side-note, definitely you should have some kind of object property checkings, for example, if your ngModel attribute is not `abc.def` - this will throw exception, so better have generic function for this

Comment: I'm sorry? Did something get cut out?

Comment: how can I make it so that it can handle abc.def and abc.def.another and abc.def.another.another?

Comment: Write function that would get all keys by splitting them with dot, loop thought keys by getting actual value from object recursively

Answer (score 0):

In JS, there's a difference between property name containing `.` (dot) and nested objects accessed by dot. So `scope.user.companyId` is something different than `scope["user.companyId"]`. You can have JS object like this:

```
{ 
   user: {
       companyId: 1
   },
   "user.companyId" : 2
}
```

So, if you really need to access property having string that represents path within the object (not single property name) you need to parse it. There are many ways to do this. Naive way would be something like this:

```
function getProperty(obj, pathString) {
  var properties = pathString.split(".");
  var result = obj;
  for (var i in properties) {
    result = result[properties[i]];
  }
  return result;
}
```

In your case can be used like this: `getProperty(scope, "user.companyId")`.

Answer (score 0):

The way you're accessing the object is incorrect in e.g.
`console.log(scope["user.companyId"]);`

This should be
`console.log(scope["user"]["companyId"]);`

I hope this helps you :-)

Comment: Assuming your object is somewhat like this:
scope.user = { companyId: 1 }